# How to improve the performance of this PHP code?

Tags: php, algorithm, performance

This is the structure of the php code that I am using

```
$Objects = $account->api1(); // This returns an object array with each object being O(data1, data2, data3)
$retValue = array();
foreach($Objects as $O)
{
    if($O->data2 == 'something')
    {
        $data4 = $account->api2($O->data2); // returns a value $data4
        // Initialize $tmp;
        $tmp->data1 = $O->data1;
        $tmp->data3 = $O->data3;
        $tmp->data4 = $data4;
        $retValue[] = $tmp;
    }
}
```

Basically what I need is an object array of the following for which data2 = 'something'

```
 O(data1,data3,data4)
```

Is there a way in which I can simplify this process. Each api call costs money and also involves request across request which makes this process both costly and also slow.Can this be improved anyway ? Even little bit improvement in performance/no of calls would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you implement a request cache? Seems like poor API design if you need to make looping API calls over a dataset.

Comment: Don't think he could as it cost "money" on each request imply the api is external services

Comment: You make an assignment in your condition, I don't think it's what you want to do. `if($O->data2 = 'something')` should be `if($O->data2 == 'something')`

Comment: What is `$data2`? (Also, this question is more likely appropiate for Code Review Comunity - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Another thing: you do this `$data4 = $account->api2($data2);` but you never use `$data4`....

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** I'll assume you have some typos in your question and the following equivalences

- <s>`$data2` means `$O->data2`</s> Fixed in the question
- <s>`$O->data4` means `$data4`</s> Fixed in the question

---

Calling `$account->api2($O->data2)` should always return the same value
because you always check that `$O->data2` is equal to *"something"*..
So you can call it just once, insteand of each time you have a hit.

```
<?php

    $Objects = $account->api1(); // This returns an object array with each object being O(data1, data2, data3)
    $retValue = array();

    foreach($Objects as $O)
    {
        if($O->data2 == 'something')
        {

            // Here, you just call api2 the first time (or never, maybe, if you never needed to)
            $data4 = isset($data4) ? $data4 : $account->api2($O->data2);

            // Initialize $tmp;
            $tmp->data1 = $O->data1;
            $tmp->data3 = $O->data3;
            $tmp->data4 = $data4;
            $retValue[] = $tmp;
        }
    }

?>
```